# Android: Override cached images from ImageLoader

Tags: android, caching

I cached a few pictures like a profile pic of some users. But now, when the user changes the profile pic, the cached image will be loaded..
Here is my code:

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

// user profile pic
                profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);
```

and I cached it with:

```
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(item.getProfilePic(), profilePic, options, animateFirstListener);
```

Well, the question is how can I override the cached image, if the user uploads a new profile pic?

Comment: I think you have to build your own logic. Having a table for example in the backend saying the last time the user updated his/her profile picture.
And then that metadata has to be linked to the cached picture in your app. Then, you will be checking that table at the app launching or on your activity lauching (depending how you want it...)

Comment: Sometimes, it changed automatically, sometimes not I don't get it :-D

Comment: Well, I guess it changes only when the app is relaunched...

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by removing the cached image and load a new one.

```
MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
DiscCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());    
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, (ImageView) view);
```